# UISplitview orientation not change in iOS 5 and iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have using split view in my application.
When i run my application in iOS 6 simulator it rotates as per orientation changes and works well but when i run same application in iOS 5 or iOS 5.1 simulator and i change orientation of simulator but split view not changes as per orientation change.
I also add code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

And I add split view using following code
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    return YES;
    }

above method in both Master View and Detail View.

And I added split view using following code

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
     // obj_PageControlViewController = [[PageControlViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PageControlViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];

     MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

     masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

     self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
     self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
     self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];
     TabBarAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TabBarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:self.splitViewController];

}
```

but it's not work. Any one can help me?

Comment: Did you select the supported interface orientations in your project summary ? (click on your project on the left bar, then in the middle window the first section, select all the orientations your app can support)

Comment: No I didn't select orientation in my project summary.

Answer (score 4):

You say you added `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` but you didn't say *where* you added it. To get autorotation of a UISplitViewController in iOS 5.1 or earlier, you must supply `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in the view controllers of *both* child view controllers of the split view controller (both the master and the detail view controllers).

That will work, assuming that the split view controller is the top-level (root) view controller of your application, as set up by the Master-Detail template.

Oh, and save yourself some trouble: in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, just return YES. On iPad, you always want to autorotate.

Comment: I added shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in both Master view and Detail view and I set split view as a root view. When I rotate my device background of the view is rotated but the content of split view  remains at it is like portrait view.

Comment: It sounds like there's an extra view or view controller in there. Make a new project using the Master Detail Application Template for iPad; that's how a UISplitViewController should be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS5 and below you should use

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

The one you posted above (shouldAutorotate) is for iOS6+

Comment: I think above method is for below iOS6. And It will be not called when you run application in iOS 6 simulator. But this method will call in below iOS 6.